# How to create action links based on current route values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a page which URL is `http://localhost:5947/Employer/Edit?LoginID=41` and from that page I have a link created by `@Html.ActionLink("Change password", "change_pass", "Employer");` that redirects to the change password page.

How do I pass the `LoginID` from the edit page to the change password page?

Comment: I think yes... I don't now If it is correctly name of this problem in english...

Comment: Sidebar: why are you passing the LoginID as part of the query string?

Comment: Becouse in previusly page I choice one user from the user list/table. And in this page editing his data, and I use LoginID to collate with LoginID in database. 
I hope I good understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Change password", 
    "change_pass", 
    "Employer", 
    new { LoginID = Request["LoginId"] }, 
    null
)
```

This being said passing the login id as query string parameter raises some serious concerns about the security of your application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `ActionLink` overload that allows you to set route values. For example, you could do:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Change password", 
    "change_pass", 
    "Employer", 
    new { LoginID = Request["LoginID"] }, 
    null)
```

However, you could improve on this by not accessing the `Request["LoginID"]` directly. To do this, the model for the `Edit` view must have a property for the current `LoginID` and use that property instead.